# Circled Label Xamarin Forms

Tags: label, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

### What I want to Achieve:

A seen in the below screenshot there is a label with a hole number, I want to create a circle around this label,how would I go about achieving this?

[image: Label that Requires Circle]

Now my assumption is that to achieve this I will need to create a custom renderer and override the Label class but from there I'm not sure how I would draw the circle and achieve the expected results.

Any guidance and assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add an Image under the number, for better alignment you may need to break the label into two labels and put them both in a Grid, each in its own cell- hacky but gets the job done in a cross-platform manner

Comment: Hi Sten, Thanks for your input. I am going to try implement the solution proposed by pete and if all else fails ill use the workaround listed above :)

Comment: By all means - custom renderer is the more civilized way to go, that's why I only put my suggestion as a comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the following link you will find the code and video for a **RoundedBoxView** (half way down the page).

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17792/video-on-making-custom-renderers

If you create this within your project you can then do the following to create your *rounded box label*:-

*) **Grid** as the outer control.

*) Create a **RoundedBoxView** as a *child* of the **Grid** to create your circle - You could either specify fixed width/height on the grid outer control to know what value to specify the **RoundedBoxView**'s **CornerRadius** property, or alternatively hook into the **SizeChanged** event handler to set the values.

*) Create a **Label** control also as a child of the **Grid** control, and center the position of it.

You can then create your **Hole** text in a **Label** within a *horizontal* **StackLayout** and then add the above in to create the effect you desire.

Comment: Glad I could help.  If you need any further advice or help then always remember I am contactable outside this website as well, see my Profile for contact info.