# Xamarin Forms listview item with label+circle background

Tags: listview, label, xamarin.forms, geometry

I want to design my ListView in Xamarin Forms for Android and IOS.

I want to make this item list : [image]

My problem is the circle with the number. In fact, i don't know how i can make circle in Xamarin Forms.

This is my itemTemplate:

```
<ViewCell.View>
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="10" BackgroundColor="{Binding RowColor}">
    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="White" FontSize="20"
           LineBreakMode="NoWrap" />
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Text="{Binding BarcodeMessage}" Grid.Column="0"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="White" /> 
        <Label Text="{Binding Quantity}" Grid.Column="1"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="White" />
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366718/circled-label-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Label with a circle as the background image, then place the text inside of it.  Alterantely, with a grid you could use an Image control with a Label (with transparent background) layered on top of it.

There is also a [RoundedBoxView](https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/RoundedBoxView) plugin that might be useful.

Comment: Hum ! I must to put an image, i Xamarin has not a control to do circle ?

Comment: now you can achieve this with frame and its cornerradius property