# How To Draw a circle with a text in the center using Xamarin Forms C# Without using custom-renderer?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, ngraphics

I am new to xamarin forms and I have to draw a Circle with label positioned at the center of the circle, the content of the label is dynamic, so it must support data binding and the circle should adapt to contains the text.

**note: the text is digits mainly and I don't have to support text with more than two digits.**

in the following question 
[Circled Label Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366718/circled-label-xamarin-forms)

they explain how to achieve that using Custom renderer, however I don't feel like such a task needs the complexity of customer renderers as long as there are NControl and NGraphics Libraries that -I think- can satisfy the requirements.

Could you please guide me on how to achieve such task using NGraphics and NControl Libraries?

Answer (score 25):

If you don't want to use a button you can also use a frame.

```
<Frame HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" CornerRadius="20" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="Maroon">
    <Label Text="7" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
</Frame>
```

Credit goes to this forum https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/99509/how-make-a-circle-label#Comment_322491

Comment: +1 For the most part, this is correct. But at times you need to account for `LineHeight` which is troublesome to use in Xamarin.Forms. Especially when centering small text inside small views. The little `LineHeight` difference makes the look off center.

Comment: Crucial to set the padding to 0 or you won't get a perfect circle.

Comment: Easiest and best solution BY FAR!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to make a button with round corners and a text inside, like this:

```
<Button BackgroundColor="Red"
        Text="{Binding yourText}"
        TextColor="White"
        FontSize="Small"
        BorderWidth="1"
        BorderRadius="100"
        WidthRequest="150"
        HeightRequest="150" />
```

Comment: you're missing the d

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be possible without custom renders you have to use with custom renders only

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that inherits from NControlView and add a bindable property for the text so it supports data binding. Since NControlView inherits from ContentView, it can house a Label which can display your text.

You can draw a circle by overriding the Draw() method and using canvas.FillEllipse().

A simple example below. I'm not sure how to calculate the size of the circle based on how long the text is, but this should get you started.

```
public class CircleLabel: NControlView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(CircleLabel), default(string));
    public string Text {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    protected Label _label;

    public CircleLabel()
    {
        _label = new Label() {
            TextColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.White,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = Xamarin.Forms.TextAlignment.Center
        };
        _label.BindingContext = this;
        _label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Text");

        // add the label to the ContentView
        Content = _label;
    }

    public override void Draw(NGraphics.ICanvas canvas, NGraphics.Rect rect)
    {
        base.Draw(canvas, rect);

        // draw an orange circle
        canvas.FillEllipse(rect, NGraphics.Colors.Orange);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Grid>
           <BoxView VerticalOptions="Center" Opacity="0.5"  HorizontalOptions="Center" Color="LightSlateGray"  CornerRadius="61" WidthRequest="122" HeightRequest="122"/>
            <BoxView VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Color="White" CornerRadius="60" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="120"/>
            <Grid  VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="35" Grid.Row="0" Source="refresh.png"/>
                <Label FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1" Text="refresh"/>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to draw a danish speed limit sign within a grid and accomplished this using Xamarin Forms 5 (per-release)  Shapes

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="12*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="42*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="46*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Ellipse Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"></Ellipse>
    <Label Text="50" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,-30,0,0"></Label>
  </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```