# Customise ListView using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to create a `ListView' like the attached screen shot using Xamarin Forms.

[image]

Comment: Do you want each row of ListView to be designed like this?

Comment: Yes Himanshu.I got couple of records in database need to populate them as per above design.

Comment: Yes that's possible by customizing ListView Cell Appearance: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ListView  x:Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{Binding image}" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="1">
                        <Label Text="{Binding property1}" TextColor="#f35e20" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="2">
                        <Label Text="{Binding property2}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="#503026"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Column="3">
                        <Label Text="{Binding property3}" HorizontalTextAlignment"Center" TextColor="#503026"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

You can use https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ImageCirclePlugin to create circular image for the first column.

Comment: I don't have an image at the moment to display, now the whole row appears white with few property and when click on it displays orange color.

Comment: You need to customize the ViewCell to change the color on selection of the row

Answer (score 1):

To design something like this, you can take a `Grid` layout with `1 row` and `4 column`.

In `1st column`: you can draw shape like this:[How To Draw a circle with a text in the center using Xamarin Forms C# Without using custom-renderer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40970510/how-to-draw-a-circle-with-a-text-in-the-center-using-xamarin-forms-c-sharp-witho)

```
<Frame HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" CornerRadius="20" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="Maroon">
<Label Text="7" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
```

In other columns, you can have `Stacklayout` with `padding` `1` and `BackgroundColor` black applied in it, containing `Label` with `BackgroundColor` Blue and text in it.

Hope this may solve your issue.

Comment: Is it easy to create one with Grid ?

Comment: Yes, you can create it easily, find reference here to create Grid inside Listview: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/99660/grid-in-listview

Comment: Ok will try that